# Drupal 7 extra class added to page

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

Drupal 7 extra class added to page

In Drupal 7, sometime a views can add class contextual-links-region here.
So it makes the contextual link show up in all the views, not just the view you mouse over on.

Where/how is the class added here ?
How to remove this class from #page ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to do it, but if you still want it, the class "contextual-links-region" is added by views module using JavaScript.

From views module:

```
/**
 * Implements MODULE_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function views_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // If the page contains a view as its main content, contextual links may have
  // been attached to the page as a whole; for example, by views_page_alter().
  // This allows them to be associated with the page and rendered by default
  // next to the page title (which we want). However, it also causes the
  // Contextual Links module to treat the wrapper for the entire page (i.e.,
  // the <body> tag) as the HTML element that these contextual links are
  // associated with. This we don't want; for better visual highlighting, we
  // prefer a smaller region to be chosen. The region we prefer differs from
  // theme to theme and depends on the details of the theme's markup in
  // page.tpl.php, so we can only find it using JavaScript. We therefore remove
  // the "contextual-links-region" class from the <body> tag here and add
  // JavaScript that will insert it back in the correct place.
  if (!empty($variables['page']['#views_contextual_links_info'])) {
    $key = array_search('contextual-links-region', $variables['classes_array']);
    if ($key !== FALSE) {
      unset($variables['classes_array'][$key]);
      // Add the JavaScript, with a group and weight such that it will run
      // before modules/contextual/contextual.js.
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'views') . '/js/views-contextual.js', array('group' => JS_LIBRARY, 'weight' => -1));
    }
  }
}
```

You can remove a JS file by implementing `hook_js_alter()`